# Intuition for gradient of steepest descent direction of a plane?

Tags: geometry, partial-derivative, gradient-descent

Assume I have a vector $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with elements $v=\left[x,y,z\right]^T$. Assume further that there is a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ for which $v$ is the steepest descent direction in $z$ if $z \ne 0$. Finally, assume that the coordinate system is rotated arbitrarily along the $z$ axis, so that the composition of the $xy$-components of $v$ is relatively arbitrary.

I wish to understand how the gradient of this plane $\left[\frac{dz}{dx},\frac{dz}{dy}\right]^T$ is composed. For this I would look at a few scenarios:

- **The $xy$ components of $v$ follow along either the $x$ or $y$ axis**. In that case, the gradient would be $\left[\frac{z}{x},0\right]^T$ or $\left[0,\frac{z}{y}\right]^T$, depending on whether the $xy$ component was $\left[x,0\right]^T$ or $\left[0,y\right]^T$.
- **The $xy$ components of $v$ follow along a diagonal of the $xy$ plane**. In that case, we would have $|x|=|y|$ and the gradient would be $\left[0.5\frac{z}{x},0.5\frac{z}{y}\right]^T$.

From how I see it, both cases could be explained with the following formula:

$$\left[\frac{dz}{dx},\frac{dz}{dy}\right]^T=\left[z\frac{|x|}{|x|+|y|},z\frac{|y|}{|x|+|y|}\right]^T$$

**Now my question**: Is this assumption correct? Does it generalize for arbitrary $xy$-components of $v$?

Comment: What do you mean by "steepest descent direction in $z$"?

Comment: I probably did not define this very clearly, sorry. There could be infinitely may planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which contain $v$, but only one for which $v$ is the steepest descent direction (i.e., where $v$ points straight down the maximum gradient of the plane).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving the plane equation for $z$ to obtain $z$ as a function of $x$ and $y$, or, as I shall write it, $z = f(x,y)$, the gradient is, as you note, $\nabla f = \left[ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x},\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right]^T$. Its norm determines the slope in the direction of steepest ascent. So the slope in the direction of steepest descent is $-|\nabla f|$.

On the other hand, the slope determined by your vector $v = [x,y,z]^T$ is equal to its "rise" over its "run," or $\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$. Therefore
\begin{equation}
|\nabla f| = -\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
\end{equation}
Because $v$ points down the plane in the direction of steepest descent, $\lbrack x,y \rbrack^T$ must be parallel to $\nabla f$ and point in the opposite direction. So we could obtain the gradient by normalizing $-\lbrack x,y \rbrack^T$ and then multiplying by the length of the gradient. So
\begin{equation}
\nabla f = |\nabla f| \cdot \frac{-1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \left[ x,y \right]^T = \frac{z}{x^2+y^2} \left[ x,y \right]^T = \left[ \frac{zx}{x^2+y^2},\frac{zy}{x^2+y^2} \right]^T
\end{equation}
The short answer is that no, your formula isn't quite correct. You need $x^2 + y^2$ instead of $|x| + |y|$.

Comment: Oh yes, there seem to be some clear errors in my derivation - the absolute values $|x|$ and $|y|$ in the numerator make no real sense upon second reflection. It seems a bit unintuitive to see why the 'weights' (e.g.,$\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$) contain the squared norm, but your derivation given the 'aligned gradient' $|\nabla f|$ and the normalized vector seems reasonable. I'll have to sit down and think about it some more =) Thanks for the answer!

Comment: For what it's worth, I plotted it a couple times just to make sure it made sense. I think it might be more intuitive if you look at it this way. The final answer needs to depend on the direction, but not the length, of the vector. The way you have it, multiplying the vector $\lbrack x,y,z \rbrack^T$ by a scalar would end up multiplying your formula for the gradient by the scalar as well. With $x^2+y^2$ in the denominator, it divides out.

Comment: It also agrees with your (correct) formula in the case that $x=0$ or $y=0$.

Comment: A continuing question, if I may... If I extend this thinking to higher-dimensional $z$ as well (but still assume that the gradient follows a simple vector), i.e. looking at $v=\left[x_1,x_2,z_1,z_2\right]^T$, the scalar slope would be $|\nabla f|=\frac{\sqrt{z_1^2+z_2^2}}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}$, right? Then the full vector would be $\nabla f=z_{norm}|\nabla f|x_{norm}^T$, with $z_{norm}=\left[z_1,z_2\right]^T/\frac{1}{\sqrt{z_1^2+z_2^2}}$ and $x_{norm}=\left[x_1,x_2\right]^T/\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}$. This looks like the Singular Value Decomposition in reverse! Is this assumption correct?

Comment: What you'd have to do is solve the hyperplane equation for $x_4$ (or whatever variable) to get something like $x_4 = f(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. Then the gradient $\nabla f$ would be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and the "slope" of $\lbrack x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4 \rbrack^T$ (defined as rate of change of $x_4$ in the direction of $\lbrack x_1,x_2,x_3 \rbrack^T$) would be $\frac{x_4}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sorry, I didn't specify this clearly enough. In my case, I assume the function would be $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, I assume for higher dimensions the the denominator would just be a higher-dimensional norm, as you mentioned. My question was more related about what happens when the numerator of the gradient ($z$) is no longer scalar.